# Why aren't augmented assignment expressions allowed?

Tags: python

I was recently reading over [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#relative-precedence-of) on assignment expressions and stumbled upon an interesting use case:

```
# Compute partial sums in a list comprehension
total = 0
partial_sums = [total := total + v for v in values]
print("Total:", total)
```

I began exploring the snippet on my own and soon discovered that `:+=` wasn't valid Python syntax.

```
# Compute partial sums in a list comprehension
total = 0
partial_sums = [total :+= v for v in values]
print("Total:", total)
```

I suspect there may be some underlying reason in how `:=` is implemented that wisely precludes `:+=`, but I'm not sure what it could be. If someone wiser in the ways of Python knows why `:+=` is unfeasible or impractical or otherwise unimplemented, please share your understanding.

Comment: Because there almost always a better way to do it. Like `sum(values)` in this case.

Comment: I think you forgot to add `:+=` in the second example.

Comment: It's not necessarily unfeasible just because it's not implemented. Assignment expressions are pretty new; they didn't add every possible variation in the first go.

Comment: Just because Python got the `:=` operator does not mean that `:+=` is (or should be) automatically added to the language as well.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you know about `itertools.accumulate`?

Comment: There was no real need to discover this on your own because the PEP covers it explicitly. And your question is, I believe, at least tangentially answered later in the PEP, at *With assignment expressions, why bother with assignment statements?*

Comment: @BoarGules That section just says that `+=` requires an assignment statement, not why there couldn't be an augmented assignment expression. (IMO, the reason is to avoid adding yet another avenue for side effects.)

Comment: `x += y` is useful, because it does more than just `x = x + y`; it translates to `x = x.__iadd__(y)`. For immutable objects there is basically no difference, but mutable objects such as lists will get updated in place. However the in-place methods of mutable objects all return `None` so that's hardly useful in an assignment expression.

Comment: @a_guest For example `[1].__iadd__([2])` doesn't return `None` but `[1, 2]`. Do you mean something else?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Oh right, seems like I confused that with `list.extend`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

###### The short version: The addition of the walrus operator was incredibly controversial, and they wanted to discourage overuse, so they limited it to only those cases for which a *strong* motivating use case was put forward, leaving `=` the convenient tool for all other cases.

[There's a lot of things the walrus operator won't do](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#differences-between-assignment-expressions-and-assignment-statements) that it *could* do (assigning to things looked up on a sequence or mapping, assigning to attributes, etc.), but it would encourage using it all the time, to the detriment of the readability of typical code. Sure, you could choose to write more readable code, ignoring the opportunity to use weird and terrible punctuation-filled nonsense, but if my (and many people's) experience with Perl is any guide, people will use shortcuts to get it done faster now even if the resulting code is unreadable, even by them, a month later.

There are other minor hurdles that get in the way (supporting all of the augmented assignment approaches with the walrus would add a ton of new byte codes to the interpreter, expanding the eval loop's `switch` significantly, and [potentially inhibiting optimizations/spilling from CPU cache](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89279)), but fundamentally, your motivating case of using a list comprehension for side-effects is a misuse of list comprehensions (a functional construct that, like all functional programming tools, is not intended to have side-effects), as are most cases that would rely on augmented assignment expressions. The strong motivations for introducing this feature were things you could reasonably want to do and couldn't without the walrus, e.g.

1. Regexes, replacing this terrible, verbose arrow pattern:

   ```
   m = re.match(r'pattern', string)
   if m:
       do_thing(m)
   else:
       m = re.match(r'anotherpattern', string)
       if m:
           do_another_thing(m)
       else:
           m = re.match(r'athirdpattern', string)
           if m:
               do_a_third_thing(m)
   ```

   with this clean chain of tests:

   ```
   if m := re.match(r'pattern', string):
       do_thing(m)
   elif m := re.match(r'anotherpattern', string):
       do_another_thing(m)
   elif m := re.match(r'athirdpattern', string):
       do_a_third_thing(m)
   ```
2. Reading a file by block, replacing:

   ```
   while True:
       block = file.read(4096)
       if not block:
           break
   ```

   with the clean:

   ```
   while block := file.read(4096):
   ```

Those are useful things people really need to do with some frequency, and even the "canonical" versions I posted are often misimplemented in other ways (e.g. applying the regex test twice to avoid the arrow pattern, duplicating the `block = file.read(4096)` once before loop and once at the end so you can run `while block:`, but in exchange now `continue` doesn't work properly, and you risk the size of the block changing in one place but not another); the walrus operator allowed for better code.

The listcomp accumulator isn't (much) better code. `itertools.accumulate` exists, and even if it didn't, the problem can be worked around in other ways with simple generator functions or hand-rolled loops. The PEP does describe it as a benefit (it's why they allowed walrus assignments to "escape" comprehensions), but the discussion relating to this scoping special case was even more divided than the discussion over adding the walrus itself; you *can* do it, and it's arguably useful, but it's not something where you look at the two options and immediately say "Man, if not for the walrus, this would be awful".

And just to satisfy the folks who want evidence of this, note that they [explicitly blocked some use cases that would have worked for free](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#exceptional-cases) (it took extra work to make the grammar prohibit these usages), specifically to prevent walrus overuse. For example, you *can't* do:

```
x := 1
```

on a line by itself. There's no technical reason you can't, at all, but they *intentionally* made it a syntax error for the walrus to be used without being wrapped in something. `(x := 1)` works at top level, but it's annoying enough no one will ever choose it over `x = 1`, and that was the goal.

**Until someone comes up with a common code pattern for which the lack of `:+=` makes it infeasibly/unnecessarily ugly (and it would have to be *really* common and *really* ugly to justify the punctuation filled monstrosity that is `:+=`), they won't consider it.**

Answer (score 2):

The itertools module provides a lot of the mechanisms to achieve the same result without bloating the language:

```
partial_sums = list(accumulate(values))
total        = partial_sums[-1]
```

Answer (score -3):

1. My understanding is that a major part of comprehension efficiency is that the calculations for each element in the original iterable can be performed in parallel. If you're calculating a running total, that has to be performed in series.
2. We already have `sum(values)`, so what does this add in this use case?
3. If you want something for more general use cases, `functools` has `reduce`.

Comment: Point 1 is incorrect; the Python language spec requires comprehensions to be executed like loops, not in parallel, and the Python docs include examples where the value in one iteration may depend on a result from the previous iteration. I am not aware of any implementation of Python which automatically converts comprehensions into parallel computations, and this would be invalid in many cases so an implementation which did this would need a way of telling whether the conversion is valid before doing it. Either way, the existing walrus operator would have exactly the same problem.

Comment: "My understanding is that a major part of comprehension efficiency is that the calculations for each element in the original iterable can be performed in parallel. " Mmm no. A list comprehension is basically just a python level for loop. It is not more efficient than that, although, there a couple of built in optimizations (caching of the append operation so you don't resolve the method each time). List comprehensions are not for efficiency* they are for readability

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What do you mean with "caching of the append operation"? As far as I can tell, it's done with the special `LIST_APPEND` bytecode which makes ceval.c call a function in listobject.c. I don't see "caching" in that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried `for i in range(10**power):
    total+=i` and `total = sum(i for i in range(10**power))`, and the latter was less than half the time of the former at power =5. Comprehensions definitely have optimization other than just caching append.

Comment: @Acccumulation That's not a list comprehension at all. That's a built-in function consuming a generator.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I don't what implementation Python uses, but one option is to build the final list in a binary matter: the first 2 items are combined into a list, then that's combined with the next 2, and a list of the next 4 is generated similarly, then those two lists of 4 are combined to a list of 8, etc. This will result in O(ln n) extend operations.

Comment: @Acccumulation But each extended operation still has to iterate over its argument. You are still doing O(n) work over all, but with additional overhead of creating temporary lists that need to be merged.

Comment: @Acccumulation I really have zero idea why you're telling me that.

Comment: @chepner I tried with a list comprehension, and the for-loop was still took nearly 20% more time, and in the past I've found list comprehension sometimes goes faster than consuming a generator. As for your other comment, the question is how expensive the extend operation is. If it's significantly more expensive than iteration, there can still be saving. If every time you append to a list, you create a new list and move every element over, then a for-loop will have have to move elements O(n^2) times.

Comment: @Acccumulation That's not how `append` work. It overallocates so that only occasionally do you need to copy the entire array into a new, larger block of memory. The amortized cost of `append` is O(1), though it's still not as fast as if you could allocate an appropriate sized array in the first place (eliminating the need to resize the array at all).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I mean it caches the method resolution, equivalent to useing `list_append = mylist.append` in a loop instead of `mylist.append`, and yes, it has it's own bespoke op code which makes it even more direct at the bytecode level (saving even a name resolution operation)

Comment: @Acccumulation see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/829cd481bad0044da933cd18c202ce9b)

Comment: @Acccumulation all of that is absolutely incorrect. You are fundamentally mistaken about how `list.append` works. It's a highly tuned, amortized O(1) operation. In *any case* you can use `dis.dis` *yourself* (see above link) to dissasemble a list comprehension and you will see it is exactly equivalent to a python-level for-loop with `append`, except it caches the method resolution (and I believe one final bytecode trick at the end). There are many reasons why your loop version might be going slower, one big one is that you are doing it in the global scope, which will slow everything down